How malicious are approvals on default ERC standards?
Assuming i have deployed contract A, that is a marketplace for tokens. Contract A uses all default OpenZeppelin interfaces.
Multiple approve for example unlimited USDT to contract A.
After some weeks, the deployer private keys of contract A are compromised by a team member.
Now here's my question: Can someone abuse contract A for transfering all approved tokens to a random wallet, effectivly taking hostage of tokens? Or is it safe to assume that the approved tokens can never be moved outside the contract, given there are no malicious or explicit functions available to do this action?
TL;DR: Is it safe to have users with allowances on a compromised contract?
(if not, an example playground would be appreciated to mimic the situation)
